# Sorry, that page does not exist [code] => 34

Tags: php, post, twitter, oauth

`POST /statuses/retweet` is giving me this error while `POST statuses/tweet` and `GET search/tweets` are working fine.

```
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";

$con = $this->oauth();
$retweets = $con->post('statuses/retweet/', array('id' => $searchid));
```

The query will get the Status `id_str` of the object. It is in string format.

```
/**
* POST wrapper for oAuthRequest.
*/
function post($url, $parameters = array()) {
   $response = $this->oAuthRequest($url, 'POST', $parameters);
   if ($this->format === 'json' && $this->decode_json) {
      return json_decode($response);
   }
   return $response;
}
```

API console gives me no error:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/{id}.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retweet the tweet with ID `1234` you need to send a POST request to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/1234.json
```

It looks like you are trying to perform a GET request to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/?id=1234
```

Comment: oh sorry bout that. i was checking if get is working. actually it doing POST.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. Retweet ID cant be sent as paramemeter. It has to be added as part of url. 
This is what i did. parameter to be null

```
$retweets = $con->post('statuses/retweet/'.$searchid, null);
```